# Angular-xeditable Editable row

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I am using x-editable Editable row, it's default having each row is editable functionality.

But i would like to do one row editable. If i double click on first row it's should be editable when click on other row first row should be non-editable and current row should be editable.

```
jsfiddle.net/premraj10/NfPcH/363/
```

Thanks